# EF Core Include, Where, and ThenInclude

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, hyperlink

I have to gather data from a DB where the deleted records are not really deleted, instead, they are flagged (there is an "IsActive" bit column where the deleted items hold the value 0).

I'm using Entity Framework Core, and I want to get a list of currencies (euro, dollar, ...). Each currency is associated to 1-n countries, so there are 3 columns at play here :

- Currency (Id, Name, ...)
- CurrencyCountry (CurrencyId, CountryNumericCode)
- Country (NumericCode, Name, ...)

I'd like to get all the currencies and their countries in one ef call; so I do have something like that :

```
_ctx.Currency
.Where(c => c.IsActive)
.Include(c => c.CurrencyCountry)
.ThenInclude(cc => cc.CountryNumericCodeNavigation)
.ToList();
```

This almost works; the sole issue is that I need to specify that I only want the active "CurrencyCountries". So I'd like to add a "Where IsActive == true" after the "Include", and before the "ThenInclude", but it looks like it cannot be done.

Is there another way of accomplish what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Off the top of my head i think you may need to do an ANY somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting your query from the junction table instead of `Currency`?

```
ctx.CurrencyCountry
.Include(c => c.Currency)
.Include(c => c.Country)
.Where(c => c.Country.IsActive && c.CurrencyCountry.IsActive)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need a list of currency though (but I could transform the list in-app ?). Another issue with this solution is that if there is a Currency with no associated countries, they wont appear in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'd like to add a "Where IsActive == true" after the "Include", and before the "ThenInclude", but it looks like it cannot be done.

It is still an on-going discussion from this topic:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833

A workaround is that you could filter data manually in `Select` which is a little complex:

```
_ctx.Currency
    .Where(c => c.IsActive)
    .Include(c => c.CurrencyCountry)
    .ThenInclude(cc => cc.CountryNumericCodeNavigation)
    .Select(c => new Currency
    {
        //populate other fields in Currency model here
        CurrencyCountry = c.CurrencyCountry.Where(item => item.IsActive).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows easily filter included entities.

The `ThenInclude` is not yet supported but you just have to include the last filter to have the same behavior.

Example:

```
_ctx.Currency
.Where(c => c.IsActive)
.IncludeFilter(c => c.CurrencyCountry.Where(c => c.IsActive))
.IncludeFilter(c => c.CurrencyCountry.Where(c => c.IsActive).Select(cc => cc.CountryNumericCodeNavigation))
.ToList();
```